# Set white color outside boundingBox (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I have this image:

[image: src]

(or this..)

[image: src2]

How can I set to white all the area outside the boundingBox'es ?

I would like to obtain this result:

[image: desired]

Thanks

Comment: A hint, all of the cells which should *not* be turned white a) are not magenta and b) have at least 1 magenta cell somewhere above, to the left, to the right, and below them (i.e. are not inside any bounding box)

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of these rectangles being drawn ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments if you have the positions of the ROIs, you can use them to paste them on the an image with white background having the same shape as the original.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Desktop\rus.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
white_bg = 255*np.ones_like(image)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(thresh, 1)
kernel = np.ones((10, 20), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(blur, kernel, iterations=1)
im2, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    roi = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    if (h > 50 and w > 50) and h < 200:

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 1)        
        cv2.imshow('{}.png'.format(i), roi)

        #--- paste ROIs on image with white background 
        white_bg[y:y+h, x:x+w] = roi

cv2.imshow('white_bg_new', white_bg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @Link you can fine tune the result to separate out the digits. But I hope you get the idea!1

Comment: @Link how do you expect the output to be? You could perform the same on a binary threshold image as well

Comment: @Link The main idea is to paste the ROI within the selected coordinates `white_bg[y:y+h, x:x+w] = roi`

Comment: Aaaaand nothing, you're right. Sorry...
But I will wait for a mask solution (code) LOL anyway

Comment: @Link What do u mean by a mask solution? You can perform the same operation on a binary threshold image instead of the original image!

Comment: It's the same @shubham jaiswal said ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a mask with the dimensions same as that of your image. The mask is an array with values 255 (white). I assume if you are drawing the bounding box, you definitely have the coordinates for each of them. For each of the bounding box you simply replace the region in the mask with the region bounded by the bounding box as below:

`mask[y:y+h,x:x+w] = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]`, where `mask` is your final output with your desired result and `image` is your input image on which the processing is to take place. The values `x`,`y`,`w`,`h` is the same for both the image as we have made sure that the dimensions for the mask and input image are the same.