# (Python ,openCV) capture QR code sticker image from big image

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision

**If I capture a picture from production line, how can I extract the part I want from image**

from pic - https://ibb.co/k9wfTT0
to pic - https://ibb.co/BKfMx6w

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('/home/joy/桌面/test_11_2/split_img/original.png')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
idx =0 
for cnt in contours:
    idx += 1
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi=im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
   
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
cv2.imshow('img',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

my output: https://ibb.co/rkbQy7w

---

from zxing and zbar tutorial:
https://learnopencv.com/barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-using-zbar-and-opencv/

can detect QR code location, **then if I make the locate point larger, might can include the area/sticker I want** https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p6hx.jpg

- below discussion might could solve my issue (by extend locate qr code's (x,y) to cover my sticker part)
  [Python - Detect a QR code from an image and crop using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359398/python-detect-a-qr-code-from-an-image-and-crop-using-opencv)

---

(plan B)
**To public, can I just directly cut to small pieces, instead of do other process, cause I can just OCR img to text only my desire part**

the pic link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n3EK.jpg

Comment: there are zxing and zbar library to be able to read qr or barcode codes.

Comment: Is this a question from some class?  This was just asked a few posts ago. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299517/python-opencv-extract-picture-from-picture and Mark Setchell's answer.

Comment: @fmw42 , yeah I am a student in about 45 people class, cause program is not as other assignment could try as hard as you can then solution can come up, for this if you stock you just stock, I just learn python opencv not more than a month, therefore I need some advice thanks

Comment: Threshold on the white of the labels. Then get all the contours for the white regions. Then crop your original image at each of the contour bounding boxes. Then do pytesseract to read the black text.

Comment: hi @fmw42 , I think that ran too far, if we can directly locate qr code location, the (x,y) on image, then just extend the x, y that can include my expect whole sticker [link](https://imgur.com/a/UnGdjdD)

Comment: But to locate the QR code, you first need to extract the white regions

Comment: HI @FMW42 , can I just directly cut to small pieces, instead of do other process, cause I can just OCR img to text only my desire part

Comment: @DC con. Sorry, I do not understand your question. In order to cut those regions, you would have to find them first. To find them, I suggest thresholding on the white using cv2.inRange().

Answer (score 1):

by this discussion [Set white color outside boundingBox (Python, OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368683/set-white-color-outside-boundingbox-python-opencv)

the code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("/home/student_Joy/desktop/test_11_8/original.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
white_bg = 255*np.ones_like(image)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(thresh, 1)
kernel = np.ones((10, 20), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(blur, kernel, iterations=1)
im2, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    roi = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    if (h > 50 and w > 50) and h < 200:

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 1)        
        cv2.imshow('{}.png'.format(i), roi)
        cv2.imwrite(f"/home/student_Joy/desktop/test_11_8/output01/output_{x}_{y}.png", roi)

        #--- paste ROIs on image with white background 
        white_bg[y:y+h, x:x+w] = roi

cv2.imshow('white_bg_new', white_bg)

cv2.imwrite(f"/home/student_Joy/desktop/test_11_8/output01/final_output_{x}_{y}.png", white_bg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the link is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh5MX.jpg

Comment: hi classmate con, I don't know ur here